# varchar with n and varchar without n difference in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is there any difference between varchar and varchar(n) regarding any performance and disk usage in postgresql? (Except length constraint and constraint performance).
For example, does varchar(wihtout n) consume more space?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html - read the green tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`varchar`, `varchar(n)` and `text` are all the same under the hood; the only exception is the lenght check in `varchar(n)`, which acts like a (fast) check constraint.